# Where should Next.js middleware be located?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I'm using next: ^13.5.3 version.
I created middleware.js in pages/middleware.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
 
export function middleware(req) {
 ...
}
```

And giving this error: ***ESLint: next/server should not be imported outside of pages/_middleware.js. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-server-import-in-page(@next/next/no-server-import-in-page)***

The link says: ***Only import and use next/server in a file located within the project root directory: middleware.{js,ts}.***

I moved it to the root directory.

[image]

but this time it gives this error: ***ESLint: next/server should not be imported outside of pages/_middleware.js. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-server-import-in-page(@next/next/no-server-import-in-page)***

When I change it to pages/_middleware.js, I get this error while building. I'm so confused.

[image]

My Questions:

1. Should the name of the middleware file start with "_"?
2. In which directory should I place the middleware file so that I can use "NextResponse"?

Answer (score 1):

oh, i understand why.

my "eslint-config-next" version: 12.0.8

i updated latest version and fixed. I'm sorry if I wasted anyone time.